# Flask - Python WTForms, Populate form with <li> list, <a> anchor data

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am using flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2 and python and I am struggling after getting data from the database and displaying them in my html while they are inside a list and in an anchor to post them with anchor click inside a form to submit them afterwords in another database table.
Here is what I have so far.

*My html*

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div id="training_list">
<h1>List of Exercises</h1>      
{% for exercises in exlist %}
<li id="li_ex_list"><a href="#">{{ exercises.name }}</a> |&nbsp;Reputations:
{{ exercises.reps }}</li>
{% endfor %}                                    
</div>
<div id="training_content">
<h1>My Workout Plan</h1>
<form method="POST" action="/my_workouts">

</form>
</br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Save my plan</button>
</div>
</div>
```

*My flask-python*

```
class Exercises(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(40), unique=True, nullable=False)
    reps = db.Column(db.Integer(), nullable=False)
    complete = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)
    def __init__(self, name, reps, complete):
        self.name = name
        self.reps = reps
        self.complete = complete
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Exercises %r>' % self.name

class Traningplan(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    ex_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('exercises.id'), nullable=False)
    ex_name = db.Column(db.String(40), db.ForeignKey('exercises.name'), nullable=False)


class Usertrainingplan(FlaskForm):
    user_id = IntegerField('Userid', render_kw={'readonly': True})
    ex_id = IntegerField('Exerciseid', render_kw={'readonly': True})
    ex_name = StringField('Exercisename', render_kw={'readonly': True})

@app.route('/my_workouts', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def my_workouts():
    exlist = Exercises.query.all()
    form = Usertrainingplan()
return render_template('My_Training_Programs.html', exlist=exlist, form=form)
```

I have tried filtering for complete True/False and passing 2 variables for complete and incomplete(also added them with jinja2 template in my html) but I can't make it work.
---- This part was inside "def_myworkouts():"-----

```
incomplete = Exercises.query.filter_by(complete=False).all()
complete = Exercises.query.filter_by(complete=True).all()
```

---

```
    @app.route('/complete/<id>')
    def complete(id):
        exercises = Exercises.query.filter_by(id=int(id)).first()
        exercises.complete = True
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('my_workouts'))
```

**Additional Information:**
Current page looks like this:
[current page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFPFQ.jpg)

So what I want to do is:

Once the user clicks on the links on the left side, I want the text of the links (e.g. Landmine) to be added in the right side of the page where "My workout plan" is, and create a list with all the selected items.
Additionaly I want to be able to place them inside a form and the submit(POST) the form inside a table in my database, with the columns: user_id, ex_id, ex_name as foreign keys. user_id(foreign key) should be the current logged in users id(primary key), ex_id(foreign key) should be the id of the exercise and finally ex_name(foreign key) should be the name of the exercise. The primary keys ofcourse are already commited in the database in the required tables and sames goes with exercises names.

Thanks for your time in advance. Any help highly appriceated.

*Stackoverflow you are my only savior*

Comment: Its unclear what you want the final result to look like. Could you provide some more information? What does success look like? Are experiencing errors? And what are they? A useful stacktrace?

Comment: Check the additional information above. Thanks.

Comment: Your solution is going to be Javascript based-- because all this is happening on the client's web-browser (the next time Flask gets to play with the code is when 'Save My Plan' has submitted the form). So if you start by searching for how to read data from an 'onclick' event using Javascript, (e.g. reading which Exercise the user clicked') then tying that with 'adding a form input using javascript' to add an entry to your form with that onclick data you read.

Comment: Thank you I will check it out and get back to you.